# MySQL MyISAM table index cardinality is zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing 60 million rows. The structure is like `entryid, date, sourceid, detail, views`. `(entryid, date, sourceid, detail)` is the PK, and I also have indexes for each field except `views`.

The problem is the cardinalities of the four indexes are zero, but I am sure they should not.

I wonder why is that? And does it mean the index doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried running `ANALYZE TABLE` then checking again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the table statistics have not been updated.

See [this page on optimizing MyISAM tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-queries-myisam.html):

> To help MySQL better optimize queries, use ANALYZE TABLE or run
>   myisamchk --analyze on a table after it has been loaded with data.
>   This updates a value for each index part that indicates the average
>   number of rows that have the same value. (For unique indexes, this is
>   always 1.) MySQL uses this to decide which index to choose when you
>   join two tables based on a nonconstant expression. You can check the
>   result from the table analysis by using SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name and
>   examining the Cardinality value. myisamchk --description --verbose
>   shows index distribution information.

---

The best way to determine whether an index is helping [is to `explain` a query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html):

```
mysql> explain select 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | No tables used |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```